# Why an object is invisible?

Tags: java, private, visibility

I have a class. In this class I declare a a private variable `private Agent agent;`. In my class I have

```
private Thread controller = new Thread() {
...
}
```

Within the above `private thread` I call `getParameter` which is a private method of the considered class. Within the `getParameter` I call one of the methods of the `agent`. As a result I get a `NullPointerException`. So, I conclude that `agent` is not visible from the `getParameter`.

Why is that? Can it be that the reason of that is that the `getParameter` is within the `private Thread`? And, if it is the case, how the described problem can be resolved?

**ADDED**

I realized that I need to be more specific. My code is organized like that:

```
public class GameWindow {
   ...
   private Agent agent;
   ...
   private Thread controller = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
           ...
           Agent agent = new Agent();
           ...
           parameter = getParameter();
        }
  }
  ...
  private String getParameter() {   
     ...
     agent.someMethod();
     ...
  }
}
```

**ADDED 2**
In the GameWindow I have:

```
public void startWindow() {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            controller.start();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: So what code initializes the `GameWindow.agent`?

Comment: And what code starts the `controller` thread running?

Comment: You still don't show where you initialize `GameWindow.agent`.

Comment: @Anon, I thought I initialize agent by this line `Agent agent = new Agent();`.

Comment: No, that just initializes a local variable inside the `run()` method.

Comment: And some more unasked-for commentary: the `controller` and `agent` should probably be pulled out of `GameWindow` into their own class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `NullPointerException` has nothing to do with visibility. You are probably calling the `getParameter` method of a null object. Your `agent` variable is declared, but not initialiazed. You may want to code something like:

```
private Agent agent;
private Thread controller = new Thread() {
    agent = new Agent();
    // ...
    agent.getParameter(); // should not throw a NullPointerException
}
```

**UPDATE AFTER CODE WAS ADDED**

Your code has two definitions of `agent`. The first one in the class:

```
private Agent agent;
```

And the second one inside your `run()` method:

```
Agent agent = new Agent();
```

Your `getParameter()` method does not know the `agent` defined inside the `run()` method. It only knows the `agent` member of the class, which was not initialized. Your problem will be solved when you remove the second definition of `agent`:

```
public void run() {
       ...
       // Agent agent = new Agent();
       agent = new Agent(); // works fine: you are initiliazing the class member
       ...
       parameter = getParameter();
 }
```

**OLD UPDATE**:
The `NullPointerException` is thrown inside the `getParameter()` method. So I understand your code is like the following:

```
private Something getParameter() {
    agent.someMethod(); // exception thrown here
}
```

If this is your code, the problem remains the same: `agent` is not initialized. You must initialize it before calling any of its methods inside the `getParameter()` method.

Comment: No, use `getParameter` within the class (in the `private Thread`). I do not instantiate an object to call the method.

Comment: @Roman you have to instantiate the object unless the method is static

Comment: If the object is not instantiated, then it's null, hence the `NullPointerException`. Post the code where the exception is thrown so we can be sure.

Comment: getParameter is not a method of the agent. getParameter is a method of the class where the problem happens.

Comment: @Roman please check my update to my answer. The problem is still the same, anyway: `agent` is not initialized. If it was a visibility problem, your code should'nt even compile.

Comment: @Paulo Guedes, my `agent` is initialized in the `controller` before I call the `getParameter` (I put more details in my original question).

Answer (score 3):

Agent was never initialized.  You want something like this:
`Agent agent = new Agent();`

Comment: No, I do have the instantiation line (exactly as you gave it) and it is executed (I checked it by putting output before and after the line).

Comment: Please post the stack trace as this is turning into finding a needle in a stack of needles

Comment: @Roman but you are initializing the local variable agent inside the scope of the run method, not the member variable agent owned by gamewindow

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be creating this new thread in an instance initializer. Which means that the containing instance may not be fully initialized when the thread starts running (you don't show where you call `start()`).

---

And some unasked-for advice: (1) don't subclass thread, create a `Runnable`, and (2) don't create your own threads, use an `ExecutorService`

Answer (score 1):

Ditto Roman, but let me add one clarifying point.

If you do not have visibility to an object, you will get an error message when you try to compile. A null pointer exception is a RUNTIME error, not a compile-time error. You will never, ever get a null pointer exception for a visibility problem, for the simple reason that you will not be able to run the program if you have visibility problems, because the compile will have failed.

A null pointer exception means that you have not assigned an actual instance of the object to a variable. That could mean you never created an instance at all, or it could mean that you have one declaration hiding another, like here.